# Let $G$ be a group and let $X$ be a G-set. Show: If $x\in X$ and $h\in G$, then there is $y\in X$ such that $y=hx$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am unsure how to start...just need a hint, please. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well $y:=hx$ satisfies the condition ;). Probably you meant $x=hy$? Then take $y=h^{-1} x$.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ operates on $X$, by definition, $\forall h\in G,x\in X$, you have $hx\in X$. Just let $y$ be that $hx$.